# SimHub BMW E36 Cluster

Tags: racing, beamng

I am currently working on a project for my school in which I am using an Arduino and the gauges from a BMW to create an interactive gauge pod for games that use Out Gauge, such as BeamNG.drive. I am following a guide that I found on GitHub, but I am unsure whether the gauge pinout for the 318i mentioned in the post is the same for all e36 models. I came across the attached diagram on the website
[image: wiring diagram from github]

Comment: You could always plug a multimeter into it and measure the values to compare to the chart like in the good old days.